# Why do we need to add .end() to a response?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

Currently building a RESTful API with express on my web server, and some routes like the delete route for a document with mongoose ex. `await Note.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id) response.status(204).end()` send response statuses with `end()`

Why do I need to add the `.end()`? What in these cases, and why cant one just send `response.status(204)`

With some responses that return json, the `response.status(201).json` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain methods with Express or the http interface will send the response.  Some methods such as `.status()` or `.append()` or `.cookie()` only set state on the outgoing response that will be used when the response is actually sent - they don't actually send the response itself.  So, when using those methods, you have to follow them with some method that actually sends the response such as `.end()`.

In your specific example of:

```
response.status(204)
```

You can use the Express version that actually sends the response:

```
response.sendStatus(204)
```

If you choose to use `.status()` instead, then from the Express documentation, you have to follow it with some other method that causes the response to be sent.  Here are examples from the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status) for `.status()`:

```
res.status(403).end()
res.status(400).send('Bad Request')
res.status(404).sendFile('/absolute/path/to/404.png')
```

Since all three of these other methods will cause the response to be sent and when the response goes out, it will pick up the previously set status.